# Cannot Instantiate Class error Selenium Testng Maven

Tags: java

```
package com.qa.easy.testbase;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
    import com.qa.easy.testutil.WebEventListener;
    public class TestBase { 
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    public static EventFiringWebDriver e_driver;
    public static WebEventListener eventListener;
    public TestBase(){
    try {
    prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("F:\\Azar\\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins"
    + "\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\easy\\config\\config.properties"));
    prop.load(ip);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public static void initialization(){
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
    if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Installation\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    }
    e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
    // Now create object of EventListerHandler to register it with EventFiringWebDriver
    eventListener = new WebEventListener();
    e_driver.register(eventListener);
    driver = e_driver;
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }
    }
**My Page Class:**


package com.qa.easy.pages;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import com.qa.easy.testbase.TestBase;
    public class Demopage extends TestBase {
    @FindBy(className="cbt")
    WebElement CBTImage;
    @FindBy(className="round-tabs four")
    WebElement advanced;
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Table Sort & Search')]")
    WebElement tablesearch;
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='search']")
    WebElement searchbox;
    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@id='example']//tbody")
    WebElement searchresults;
    public Demopage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public boolean CBTImage() {
    return CBTImage.isDisplayed();
    }
    }
    **My Test class:**
    package com.qa.easy.testcases;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import com.qa.easy.pages.Demopage;
    import com.qa.easy.testbase.TestBase;
    public class Demotest extends TestBase{
    Demopage demopage;
    public Demotest() throws IOException {
    super();        
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
    initialization();
    demopage = new Demopage();  
    }
    @Test
    public void cbtLogo(){
    boolean flag = demopage.CBTImage();
    Assert.assertTrue(flag);
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){
    driver.quit();
    }
    }
Actual Result now:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.qa.easy.testcases.Demotest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:130)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.qa.easy.testbase.Basetest.<init>(Basetest.java:23)
    at com.qa.easy.testcases.Demotest.<init>(Demotest.java:21)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:130)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.qa.easy.testbase.Basetest.<init>(Basetest.java:23)
    at com.qa.easy.testcases.Demotest.<init>(Demotest.java:21)
```

Which means that you the following line returns a null.

```
System.getProperty("F:\\Azar\\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins"
    + "\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\easy\\config\\config.properties")
```

Comment: Thanks Joao... But my properties file is exactly in that location. Any advice to fix this or find if it's returning null value ?

Comment: Are you sure the command doesn't return null? System.getProperty expects the name of a property (os.name, e.g.) not a path to a property file. Can you add a break point and check the result of this command specifically at this point?

Comment: When I updated the line as
FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream("F:\\Azar\\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\\src\\main\\resources\\com\\qa\\easy\\config\\config.properties");

The error is java.io.FileNotFoundException.

But I'm able to find this file in the same location in my drive. any issues with access settings ?

Comment: Thanks Joao.... I found the issue. 

prop.load(ip); where the issue was.
instead of Inputstream method I changed it to Reader method and it is working fine now.

Comment: This issue may have different causes, since it's highly coupled to the state of your file system. I would try out using the user.dir property as prefix to the path. Check this answer (and others on the same link) for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/56092473/2252076

Comment: Cool. Although I've not answered directly the real problem, I would appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted - of course, if you so think it helped.